# Strange Syntax Parsing Error in Python?

Tags: python, syntax-error

Am I missing something here? Why shouldn't the code under the "Broken" section work? I'm using Python 2.6.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def func(a,b,c):
    print a,b,c

#Working: Example #1:

p={'c':3}

func(1,
     b=2,
     c=3,
     )

#Working: Example #2:

func(1,
     b=2,
     **p)

#Broken: Example #3:

func(1,
     b=2,
     **p,
     )
```

Comment: When I try this code under Python 2.6, I get a syntax error at line 19 (the second Working).

Comment: Thanks, corrected minor typo in example #2.

Comment: And (not unimportant): why would you want this extraenous comma (except for researching this behaviour)?

Comment: The trailing comma helps my eyes see that the expression is not over yet. This would help for a very long line, for example. Also, I always put trailing commas in case I want to paste in more parameters without having to modify the previous line (although that is not applicable in this instance.)

Answer (score 9):

This is the relevant bit from the [grammar](http://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html):

```
arglist: (argument ',')* (argument [',']
                         |'*' test (',' argument)* [',' '**' test] 
                         |'**' test)
```

The first line here allows putting a comma after the last parameter when not using varargs/kwargs (this is why your first example works). However, you are not allowed to place a comma after the kwargs parameter if it is specified, as shown in the second and third lines.

By the way, here is an interesting thing shown by the grammar:

These are both legal:

```
f(a=1, b=2, c=3,)
f(*v, a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

but this is not:

```
f(*v, a=1, b=2, c=3,)
```

It makes sense not to allow a comma after `**kwargs`, since it must always be the last parameter. I don't know why the language designers chose not to allow my last example though - maybe an oversight?

Answer (score 5):

Python usually allows extra commas at the end of comma-lists (in argument lists and container literals). The main goal for this is to make code generation slightly easier (you don't have to special-case the last item or double-special-case a singleton tuple).

In the definition of the grammar, `**kwargs` is pulled out separately and without an extra optional comma. It wouldn't ever help with anything practical like code generation (**kwargs will always be the last thing so you do not have to special-case anything) as far as I can imagine, so I don't know why Python would support it.